# Using copyRange with formatting equaling xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm pretty new to the VBA world and mostly self taught (this is also the result of most of my issues)
I've pieced together some code to copy data from autofilter results to a new sheet. The problem I am having is the format in which it is being copied to the target sheet - I would like it to be copied in a format similar to "xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats" format it without using actual copy/paste - Is there a way to achieve this? I prefer not to use copy/paste because the sample code is repeated several times with different filter criteria and tends to give a memory error. The sample code work great and with no memory issues with the exception of the formatting. Any help, suggestions, ego stroking (j/k) is appreciated.

P.S.: I know the filter criteria doesn't make sense but I had to remove the original criteria due to its confidential nature - sorry

```
Sub MWSB_Filter_Macro()
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim tgt As Worksheet
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long


Set src = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Named Log")
Set tgt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Named Target")

src.AutoFilterMode = False

lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set filterRange = src.Range("A5:AS" & lastRow)

Set copyRange = src.Range("A5:AS" & lastRow)


filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="MWSB"

filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="2-Criteria for 2", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="3-Criteria for 3"

filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=""

filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:=""

copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I gather it sounds like you are getting a pop-up message in the middle of run-time stating something like "clipboard full...". If this is true then you can avoid any pop-up messages occurring during run-time (and therefore use the copy/paste method you mentioned) by inserting the following at the top of your procedure:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Alternatively you could copy to destination as you have above then add code to go to that destination and change the format for the range just pasted (try recording a macro if you don't know how to do this using VBA).

Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your feedback - The message I am getting is related to memory and locks up excel - Although the line of code you provided will undoubtedly be helpful in the future it's not quite what I was fishing for - I tried recording the macro but I find that I always end up with "bloated" code